# What does Here refer to?

Tags: british-english

> The Merlion, a statue with a lion's head and the body of a fish, is a major tourist attraction. Here, visitors get a breathtaking view of Sentosa, the city skyline and the surrounding islands from two viewing decks.

What does "here" refer to?

Answer (score 2):

Here refers to the location of the "Merlion".

This would appear to be from a sightseeing advert from Singapore. The paragraph is about the Merlion, so "here" must mean "the place where the "merlion" is located.